# php can't get parameter from Xcode program writtern by Swift

Tags: php, swift

I cannot get the parameter sent from the swift code. If i ignore the parameter i can got return result. Please help. THX

Swift Code:

```
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    var searchString = ""
    var bodyData: NSString = "brandCode=BU&model=test1234"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var connection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!

    connection.start()
```

---

PHP Code:

```
    $brandCode=$_POST['brandCode'];
    $model=$_POST['model'];
    $cnx=odbc_connect('testODBC','testing','testing');
    $sql="select * from brand where brand='".$brandCode."' and model='".$model."'";
    $cur= odbc_exec($cnx, $sql);
    while($info = odbc_fetch_array($cur))
    {
        $resultArray[]=array($info); 
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: Unrelated to Swift code...When you are accessing variables from $_POST I would suggest you to use isset() function to check if certain variable is actually set.

Comment: remove this request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") and try

Comment: It works by removing the line. thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com")
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var bodyData = "brandCode=BU&model=test1234"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{
    (response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very strong in PHP, but it looks to me like you are trying to extract the model value as an URL parameter rather than from the body of the message.

You should either append your "brandCode=BU&model=test1234" string directly to your URL:

```
http://myurl.php?brandCode=BU&model=test1234
```

Or build the URL using NSURLComponents.

Adding parameters to the URL is different then transmitting data in the body of A POST.